# Laravel PHP move collection item to the top of the collections

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

This is just in case someone else has the same question and like me did not find a suitable answer to solve it.

I had a collection that had to be filtered so the active item comes first on the collections when a certain value was passed.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
    0 => array:2 [
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "Bogan, Weissnat and Jenkins"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "id" => 4
      "name" => "Grady-Barrows"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
      "id" => 7
      "name" => "Howe and Sons"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [
      "id" => 3
      "name" => "Macejkovic-Altenwerth"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Needed to move an item top based on the `id` which is passed by URL

Comment: It would help if you show an example of the input and the required output (doesn't need to be large amounts of data but it should show what you are trying to achieve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$activeId = 3; // Your active item id
$collection = $collection
      ->sortBy('id')
      ->sortBy(fn($item) => $item->id !== $activeId);
```

This will sort your collection by id and move a specific item to the top.

*(PHP7.4+ for arrow function)*

Answer (score 2):

You can simply sort the collection by a custom function:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

$data = collect([
    ["id" => 1, "name" => "Bogan, Weissnat and Jenkins"],
    ["id" => 4, "name" => "Grady-Barrows"],
    ["id" => 7, "name" => "Howe and Sons"],
    ["id" => 3, "name" => "Macejkovic-Altenwerth"],
]);

$key = "name";
$value = "Grady-Barrows";

public function moveFirst(Collection $data, string $key, mixed $value): Collection
{
    return $data->sortBy(fn($v) => $v[$key] !== $value);
}
```

It will return false (0) for the matching entry and true (1) for the rest, so the matching entry gets put on top. Using arrow functions makes for a much simpler syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did solve it.

```
public function moveOtherToTop($collection, $key, $item)
{
    return $collection->reject(function ($value) use ($item){
        return $value[$key] == $item;
    })->prepend($collection->filter(function ($value) use ($item) {
        return $value[$key] == $item;
    })[$item]);
}
```

Idea came out from [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/move-collection-item-to-end-of-collections) and [Stillat](https://stillat.com/blog/2018/04/22/laravel-5-collections-adding-an-element-to-the-beginning-of-a-collection-with-prepend.) article.

In case there is a better solution to this answer am open to suggestions.

Comment: Sorry the naming here was the issue

Answer (score 0):

I run this in Laravel 5.8

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

function moveItemToTopCollection(Collection $collection, String $key, $value) :Collection
{
    $item_to_first = null;

    // Search element to top
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        if ($item->$key == $value){
            $item_to_first = $item;
            break;
        }
    }
    // If element not found, return original collection
    if (!$item_to_first){
        return $collection;
    }
    

    // Element to top, first remove of collection, then insert to top
    return $collection->reject(function ($value) use ($item_to_first){
        return $value == $item_to_first;
    })->prepend($item_to_first);
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain what you change and why this should fix the question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [prioritize](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-collection-macros#prioritize) method from the great [spatie/laravel-collection-macros](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-collection-macros) package.